# In Symfony2, what does \DateTime mean?

Tags: php, symfony

In Symfony 2, what does this line mean:

```
$task->setDueDate(new \DateTime('tomorrow'));
```

what does `\DateTime` signify? Can it be accessed from anywhere?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

A small FYI firstly, this doesn't have anything to do with Symfony - it just happens that Symfony2 uses [namespaces](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.global.php).

When not using namespaces, the [datetime class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) is always available through `new DateTime()` - this is because you're already in the "root" namespace. However, when you're using namespaces, simply using `new DateTime()` wont work as it will look for that class in the current namespace. Example:

```
<?php

namespace MyApp\Component;

class Something
{
   function __construct()
   {
      $dt = new DateTime(); 
   }
}
```

This will cause an error (e.g. `Class 'MyApp\Component\DateTime' not found in ...`), because there is no class within the `MyApp\Component` namespace named DateTime.

This is why you found `\DateTime()`, its telling the interpreter to look in the "root" (?) namespace for the class `DateTime`.

You can also use the [`use`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php) keyword to import the `DateTime` class - the top of your script would look like - this allows you to just call `new DateTime()`:

```
<?php

namespace MyApp\Component;

use \DateTime;
```

Comment: You can also add 'use DateTime' to your class, then just 'new DateTime()', this is how you import namespaced classes into others ready for use.

Comment: @catchamonkey true. I'll add it to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.global.php

You should also see a `namespace X\Y;` at the top of the file, `\DateTime` means that the class `DateTime` is to be taken from the global namespace, instead of `X\Y`.

i.e [this DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php).

Comment: \DateTime means it's not in the current namespace. It's in the "root" namespace.

Answer (score 2):

As other said, it referenced to global namespace, and DateTime is integrated in php, look here: 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php 
so you can use it not only in symfony ;)

Answer (score 1):

\DateTime is a namespaced DateTime class. There is probably somewhere at the top of the file you're looking at that has a use \X\X deceleration. \DateTime should be accessible anywhere you can declare use \X\X