# Slash when declaring some classes

Tags: php, class

Lately I've been coming across stuff like this in PHP:

```
new \Datetime("tomorrow);
```

What is that slash for? Does it have something to do with a new PHP feature? Could someone please explain me the why we would use this syntax?

Comment: This might answer your question http://stackoverflow.com/a/15391035/1415724

Comment: Thanks Fred. That is exactly what I needed to know :)

Comment: I love the word "exactly". Made my day, cheers ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A single backslash is the "root" namespace, where all classes reside in unless they were declared to be in another namespace. In a namespaced class, all other classes will be assumed to be withhin the same namespace.

So when you have declared

```
namespace user;

class login {
    function foobar() {
        throw new Exception(123);
    }
}
```

you´d get the error "unknown class Exception", since there is no exception-class withhin the user-namespace. Throwing \Exception, on the other hand, would correctly resolve to the "root"-namespace, where most buildt-in classes are.

Answer (score 0):

Its to do with namespaces

[Heres the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it is used for accessing global classes outside a namespace.
[See example 1](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.faq.php)